# MS Access: Need to hit backspace twice to delete one character that was copied over from Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2003

When I copy text from Excel to MS Access text box, the characters copy over, but when I hit backspace it deletes half the character so essentially I have to hit backspace twice to delete on character.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What does 'half a character' mean? Is it visually partially removed? Like if you hit backspace on 'L' it will look like 'l' (this monospaced font doesn't represent what I'm trying to say well, but I think you get it). Or is it deleting some unseen hidden character leaving the 'L' intact visually on the first key stroke?

Comment: "L" becomes "l" like you said.

Comment: Saving it as a CSV file shows the hidden character: ÿ

Comment: when you save as CSV, what character encoding do you select?

Comment: Isn’t it a combining diacritic?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Export to CSV. Paste in notepad. Remove hidden character then copy and past in MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2003 of Excel, whenever you copy a cell's contents, it always adds a "carriage return" to the end of the string, sometimes represented by a "square" symbol, the way to avoid this is to select your cell in Excel and then copy the data from the formula bar instead. No extra character's when doing it this way.

Comment: But he has many extra characters, not just a carriage return at the end of the pasted text.

Comment: @Brad Where in the question does it say there are many characters?

Comment: I guess...I read it differently and it doesn't say that. Well then, the carriage return makes sense!